# setTimeout() not working and image not moving

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

My code is

```
<script>
  var theCanvas = document.getElementById("theCanvas");
  var theContext = theCanvas.getContext("2d");
  var theImage = document.getElementById("frog");
  var x = 300;
  var y = 50;
  moveProjectile();

  function drawProjectile() {
    theContext.drawImage(theImage,6,450,100,100);
  }
  function moveProjectile() {
    x += 1;
    drawProjectile();
    window.setTimeout(moveProjectile, 1000/30);
  }
</script>
```

The image will appear but it won't move. I've tried several things, including relocating the setTimeout() and replacing it with a setInterval() but nothing is working and MDM didn't help either.

Comment: Please update to your post with the actual HTML so we can best assist you here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to pass the updated x coordinate to `drawImage`. In addition, clear the canvas each time before drawing the image at its next position.

(You should also consider using `requestAnimationFrame` rather than `setTimeout` or `setInterval`.)

```js
const theCanvas = document.getElementById("theCanvas");
const theContext = theCanvas.getContext("2d");
const theImage = document.getElementById("frog");
let x = 0;
let y = 50;
moveProjectile();

function drawProjectile() {
  theContext.clearRect(0, 0, theCanvas.width, theCanvas.height);
  theContext.drawImage(theImage, x, y, 100, 100);
}

function moveProjectile() {
  x++;
  drawProjectile();
  window.setTimeout(moveProjectile, 1000 / 30);
}
```

```html
<canvas id="theCanvas"></canvas>
<img id="frog" src="https://static.scientificamerican.com/sciam/cache/file/41DF7DA0-EE58-4259-AA815A390FB37C55_source.jpg" style="display: none;">
```